Friction / Energy Calculation for Solid Particle
I want to say this is not about homework question or something else. I want to understand fundamentals of friction inside the valve. A lot of journal or book mentioned friction loss or something else, but ther is no information about this specific scenario.
I need to calculate friction force for solid material between static and rotating part. I tried to visualized this problem as you can see below.
For example, let there be dust&solid particle between Static Part (A) and Rotating Part (B). When Rotating Part (B) performs a rotational movement, the dust trapped between them will be exposed to friction. In this context, how can we calculate a) frictional force, b) total released energy, and c) released heat energy?




Which diagram is the situation you're interested in?  The first one or the second?  I must confess that I don't understand what's going on in the second one at all;  is the blue plate on the left rotating somehow?

For a nice round particle you have just reinvented ball bearings.

I'm sorry for drawings. I try to I will try to explain in more detail. The images above and below represent the same system. The upper image is a top view of system, and the lower image is a closer view, including the dust/solid particle between the void. What I am talking about as a "system" is actually a ball valve. Rotating part is "ball" and static part is "seat". Ball is rotating inside the seat. I am trying to find what if dust particles stuck between seat and ball and ball continue to rotating how can i find friction force and released heat energy? @MichaelSeifert
